# MySql join one to many relationship - for a specific userid within date range

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to draft a MySQL query to count the number of occurrences of a status code within a date range (2017-03-01 to 2017-04-01) for a specific user (userid = 41).

Here is the query I was trying to use, but not making much progress:

```
SELECT
  u.status,
  COUNT(*) AS countStatus   
FROM (SELECT programid, userid FROM portal_program_evalsusers WHERE userid=41) c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
    programid,
    status
    FROM portal_program_eval 
    WHERE (portal_program_eval.date >= '2017-03-01' AND portal_program_eval.date <= '2017-04-01')
    GROUP BY status
) u ON u.programid = c.programid
  GROUP BY u.status
```

Here is information about the tables:

```
Tbl portal_program_eval
--------------------------
programid (primary key)
status
date

Tbl portal_program_evalsusers [relational table]
--------------------------
programid 
userid
```

What am I doing wrong with the query?

The desired output is each status and the count:

```
 --------------------------
 status  | countStatus   
      1  |        6
      2  |       23
      3  |       14
```

Comment: What's the format of the date field?

Comment: @sakura :  YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: I'm asking about the declared format on MySQL server

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto: portal_program_eval.date is a DATE MySQL data type

Answer (score 0):

After some additional trial and error, I believe I found the answer to my question:

```
SELECT
  u.status,
  COUNT(*) AS countStatus   
FROM (SELECT programid, userid FROM portal_program_evalsusers WHERE userid=41 GROUP BY programid) c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT
    programid,
    status,
    date
    FROM portal_program_eval 
    GROUP BY programid
) u ON c.programid = u.programid
  WHERE (u.date >= 2017-03-01 AND u.date < 2017-04-01)
  GROUP BY u.status
```